# Pandas string ends with and create two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. One is a date column which has a space at the end with an hour, this is stored as a string.  The other column is a Count for that hour.  I am looking to create two dataframes from this data.  One with data from 7am - 6pm or the Date column ending in 7-17.  The other with the Date string ening in values from 18,19,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6. I have looked around but most of the information I can find is boolean like pandas.Series.str.endswith.

The data looks like:

```
df
    Date            Count
0   2018-11-20 0    0
1   2018-11-20 1    0
2   2018-11-20 2    0
3   2018-11-20 3    1
4   2018-11-20 4    0
5   2018-11-20 5    0
6   2018-11-20 6    0
7   2018-11-20 7    1
8   2018-11-20 8    6
9   2018-11-20 9    0
10  2018-11-20 10   0
11  2018-11-20 11   0
12  2018-11-20 12   0
13  2018-11-20 13   0
14  2018-11-20 14   2
15  2018-11-20 15   5
16  2018-11-20 16   23
17  2018-11-20 17   0
18  2018-11-20 18   0
19  2018-11-20 19   3
```

Desired output:

```
business_hours_df
    Date            Count
0   2018-11-20 7    1
1   2018-11-20 8    6
2   2018-11-20 9    0
3   2018-11-20 10   0
4   2018-11-20 11   0
5   2018-11-20 12   0
6   2018-11-20 13   0
7   2018-11-20 14   2
8   2018-11-20 15   5
9   2018-11-20 16   23
10  2018-11-20 17   0

non_business_hours_df
    Date            Count
0   2018-11-20 0    0
1   2018-11-20 1    0
2   2018-11-20 2    0
3   2018-11-20 3    1
4   2018-11-20 4    0
5   2018-11-20 5    0
6   2018-11-20 6    0
7   2018-11-20 18   0
8   2018-11-20 19   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a boolean mask:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['2018-11-20 0', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 1', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 2', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 3', 1],
        ['2018-11-20 4', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 5', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 6', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 7', 1],
        ['2018-11-20 8', 6],
        ['2018-11-20 9', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 10', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 11', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 12', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 13', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 14', 2],
        ['2018-11-20 15', 5],
        ['2018-11-20 16', 23],
        ['2018-11-20 17', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 18', 0],
        ['2018-11-20 19', 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Date', 'Count'])

mask = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: 7 <= int(x.split()[-1]) <= 17)

business_hours_df = df[mask]
non_business_hours_df = df[~mask]

print(business_hours_df)
print(non_business_hours_df)
```

**Output**

```
             Date  Count
7    2018-11-20 7      1
8    2018-11-20 8      6
9    2018-11-20 9      0
10  2018-11-20 10      0
11  2018-11-20 11      0
12  2018-11-20 12      0
13  2018-11-20 13      0
14  2018-11-20 14      2
15  2018-11-20 15      5
16  2018-11-20 16     23
17  2018-11-20 17      0
             Date  Count
0    2018-11-20 0      0
1    2018-11-20 1      0
2    2018-11-20 2      0
3    2018-11-20 3      1
4    2018-11-20 4      0
5    2018-11-20 5      0
6    2018-11-20 6      0
18  2018-11-20 18      0
19  2018-11-20 19      3
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and answer! @Daniel Mesejo